# Indices tab security exception in aws opensearch (elastic-search)

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, opensearch

I have created a opensearch elasticsearch cluster on aws. I am able to access it and create indices via my python code. But if I visit it on aws, the indices tab shows an error.[image]

I am using master-user auth to access the cluster. I am not sure what the problem is

Comment: you created cluster by enabling fine-grained access control so, to access the cluster you may have to add your iam as principal to access this cluster by go to `Security configuration` > `Access Policy` and add your `iam-arn` to your cluster policy.